# Why does this primes algorithm fail for 323?

Tags: python, algorithm, logic, primes

The following code should return False for 323, which is not prime.

```
import math as m
    def isprime(a):
        if a < 2 or a != 2 and a % 2 == 0 or str(a)[-1] == "5" and a != 5 or sum([int(i) for i in list(str(a))]) % 3 == 0 and a != 3:
            return(False)
        elif a == 2:
            return(True)
        else:
            for divisor in range(3, m.floor(m.sqrt(a))):
                if a % divisor == 0:
                    return(False)
            return(True)     # So far, fails ONLY for 323!
    print(isprime(323))   # prints "True" when this should not be!
```

However, it returns True.

Comment: In Python `range()` does not include the last value. `m.floor(m.sqrt(a))` is 17 when `a` is 323. So your range becomes `range(3, 17)` which means you never check for 17 as a divisor. You could add 1 to the range of use `m.ceil()` instead of `floor()`.

Comment: Could you clean up that first if statement? It's a bit hard to read. To start Id add an independent if a <= 2: return False then you can remove the first two conditions.

Comment: More generally your approach encodes good rules, but there is a more efficient approach. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Using ceil instead of adding one to the floor value failed in edge cases. So far, the latter has ticked all the boxes!

Comment: Though I agree that the Sieve of Eratosthenes is a better approach, to find a silver lining, I think mine is a worthy effort! Thanks for the compliment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range` is open from the right, so you need to increase its upper bound:

```
for divisor in range(3, 1 + m.floor(m.sqrt(a))):
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thanks! This completes a project on prime gaps: [Gap in Primes](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/561ea274e41ebb191e00001c/groups/5fc002156ed5a40001188e08).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the error was excluding the square root itself. In some cases, the highest factor after the number itself is one more than the square root. Again, having tried two approaches, I add that ceiling the square root does not have the same effect as simply adding 1 to it. **Only adding works.**

The following *does not* work.

```
for divisor in range(3, m.ceil(m.sqrt(a))):
```

Instead, please use:

```
for divisor in range(3, 1 + m.floor(m.sqrt(a))):
```

I would be happy to receive a mathematical explanation of why this is the case.